# How to filter through my apis with a checkbox in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, array.prototype.map

I am having some difficulty with how to filter through my API with a checkbox. I am able to console.log it but after this, I'm a bit confused. I had to map a few APIs together and within the function, I added a `document.createElement` but nothing appeared on the dom. I need to display whatever is checked via an input, in this example, I am trying to achieve `starRating`.

This is my function

```
export default function App() {
  const [hotelRooms, setHotelRooms] = useState([]);

 
 
  const fetchHotels = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG')
    const hotels = await res.json()
    
    const hotelRooms = []

    for(const hotel of hotels) {
      const res = await fetch(`https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/roomRates/OBMNG/${hotel.id}`)
      const info = await res.json()
      hotelRooms.push({ hotel, rooms: info.rooms })
    }

    setHotelRooms(hotelRooms)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotels()
  }, [])

 
 console.log(hotelRooms[1].hotel.starRating)
```

**and the return statement**

```
return (
<div className="App">
  
  <Header/>
  

  {
    hotelRooms.map(h => (
      
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={fetchHotels}/>
      
        <h2> Name: {h.hotel.name}</h2>
        <p> Description: {h.hotel.description}</p>
        <p> Rating: {h.hotel.starRating}</p>
        <p> Postcode: {h.hotel.postcode}</p>
        <p> City: {h.hotel.town}</p>
        <img src={h.hotel.images}/>
        
                           

        <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Rooms:</p>
        {
         h.rooms.map(room => (
           <div>
           <h5>Occupancy</h5>
           <div> Adults: {room.occupancy.maxAdults}</div>
           <div> Children: {room.occupancy.maxChildren}</div>
           <div> Maximum guests: {room.occupancy.maxOverall}</div>
            <div> Room type: {room.name}</div>
            <img src={room.images}/>
           </div>
         ))
        }
```

How would i go about displaying the results on the screen?

Comment: what is your data structure for "hotelRooms" variable? please includes in the question

Comment: im not sure I understand but im trying to display the following "(including hotel name, address and star rating) and room details (including room type, max adults, max children and long description)"  in a div using the mapped api via a onChange event with a checkbox.

Comment: Okay, I've got the point,  why do you need "fetchHotels" on the "onChange" method of your checkbox since you are getting all hotels and their room at component did mount (in useEffect) ?